# Integration with vector coefficients

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector

I asked this [same question in Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129186/integrating-with-vector-coefficients-in-maple), and it was suggested I might try here.  I'm more comfortable with Maple, but if I can get Mathematica to do what I'm after, so much the better.

Basically I'm trying to symbolically integrate something like this:

$\displaystyle\int \frac{a\mu-b}{||a\mu-b||^3} \mathrm{d}\mu$

where $a,b$ are vectors and $\mu$ is a scalar.  The denominator is the cube of the 2-norm of the vector, and can be found by taking the dot product of a vector with itself, and raising it to the power of $\frac{3}{2}$.

Right now in Maple I'm explicitly multiplying out the denominator and making substitutions so that the denominator, at least, is only in terms of scalars ($a \cdot a = C$, etc. ), but I hate doing it this way, because it adds a lot of bookkeeping.  Basically I'd like the computer to understand that $a * (b \cdot a)$ is not the same thing as $b * a^2$, but that $a \cdot b * c \cdot d = c \cdot d * a \cdot b$.

What's the most kosher way to do this integration in Mathematica?

**UPDATE**

This is the full integral I'm trying to do.  I'm not sure it even has an answer, but the first integral is similar to what I have above.  So I was hoping I could take any techniques that work on the simpler one above and apply them to the full problem below.

Let:
$\vec{f} = (a - c) \mu_1 + (b - c) \upsilon_1 - (x - z) \mu_2 - (y-z) \upsilon_2 - (z - c) $

where $a, b, c, x, y, z$ are vectors representing positions, and $\mu_1, \nu_1, \mu_2, \nu_2$ are scalars.

I want to find:

$\vec{F_G} = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-v_2} \int_0^{1} \int_0^{1-v_1} \! \frac{f}{||{f}||^3} \, \mathrm{d} \mu_1 \mathrm{d} \upsilon_1 \mathrm{d} \mu_2 \mathrm{d} \upsilon_2 $

Comment: Did you check the packages mentioned here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297/193 ?

Comment: Using a tensor plugin is an interesting idea.  I'll explore it a bit and see if I can get what I'm after.

Comment: Atlas 2 seems capable of what I'm after (http://www.digi-area.com/Maple/atlas/).  It's a plugin for either Maple or Maya.  Not sure I want to spend the cash on it, though.  There seems to be a few other free plugins for Mathematica that might work, too.  I'll give them a try.

Comment: Don't forget to post an answer if you solve it. Good luck!

Comment: Atlas 2 is add-on for Maple and Mathematica, not for Maple or Maya. ;) Maya is 3D animation editor (http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/)

Answer (score 7):

**It helps to do a little analysis to simplify the problem.**  This expression is integrating over a line through $\mathbf{b}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$.  By choosing a suitable coordinate system you can arrange for $\mathbf{a} = (x,0,0)$ where, to assure a unit Jacobian, $x = \|\mathbf{a}\|$ (and you can even make $\mathbf{b} = (0,b,0)$ if you like, but let's just stop here and generically take $\mathbf{b} = (a,b,c)$).  **Brute force** now succeeds:

```
ClearAll[x, a, b, c];
Integrate[{x, 0, 0} μ / Norm[{x, 0, 0} μ - {a, b, c}]^3, 
  {μ, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> Im[a] == 0 && Im[b] == 0 && Im[c] == 0 && Im[x] == 0 && a b c != 0]
```

The output, after 5 seconds, is

```
{ConditionalExpression[(2 a Abs[x])/((b^2 + c^2) x^2), x != 0], 0, 0}
```

Change back to the original coordinates to obtain the general answer.

**The key is to specify the assumptions** implicit in the question: namely, that these are *real* vectors and that the line does not pass through the origin (where the integral diverges).

Comment: The same result can be achieved by assuming that `{a, b, c, x} \[Element] Reals` instead of specifying that their imaginary parts are zero.

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but the actual problems I'm interested in (specifically integrating across two triangles' barycentric coordinates (so forming a quadruple integral)) could be difficult to set up with all the coordinate transformations.  Unless there's a reasonable way to automate those, also?

Comment: Jay, there probably is a simple way to set up the transformations.  Consider posing the problem you want answered, rather than a simplified version.  @rcollyer: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @whuber I've updated the problem.  Don't know if you have any further insights/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood ...

```
av = Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, 3}];
bv = Table[Subscript[b, i], {i, 3}];
i = Integrate[(av mu - bv)/Dot[av mu - bv, av mu - bv]^(3/2), mu]
k = i /. {x_ __, x_ __, x_ __} -> x;
```

And then your integral is **k * j**

Where

$k =\frac{1}{\left(a_1^2 \left(b_2^2+b_3^2\right)-2 a_3 a_1 b_1 b_3+a_3^2
   \left(b_1^2+b_2^2\right)-2 a_2 b_2 \left(a_1 b_1+a_3 b_3\right)+a_2^2
   \left(b_1^2+b_3^2\right)\right) \sqrt{-2 a_1 b_1 \mu -2 a_2 b_2 \mu -2 a_3 b_3 \mu
   +a_1^2 \mu ^2+a_2^2 \mu ^2+a_3^2 \mu ^2+b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2}}$

and

$    j = \frac{i}{k}$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically trying to prevent it from breaking the vectors in to their components.  It makes the resultant equation messy to put back together.  (For instance, you have $b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2$, when I'd want it to just be $||b||^2$ or even $b \cdot b$)

Comment: @belisarius Is the `i /. {x_ __, x_ __, x_ __} -> x` used to extract a common factor of the vector?

Comment: @tkott yep. Surely there is a safer way, but in this case it works OK