# how to associate a metric for tensor contraction operations?

Tags: version-9, tensors

I see that Version 9 now has some built in tensor support (which was missing back when previously asked [How to represent and manipulate abstract indexed vector (or tensor) expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297/how-to-represent-and-manipulate-abstract-indexed-vector-or-tensor-expressions)).  The docs appear to describe the following as tensor operations

```
Clear[a, b, x , y]
a = Array[x, 2]
b = Array[y, 2]
m = { {1, 0}, {0, 1}}
n = { {1, 0}, {0, -1}}
a . m . b
a . n . b
```

Here I am "contracting" two rank 1 tensors, using a Euclidean and Minkowski metric tensor respectively.

Is there a way to associate a desired metric tensor for a set of operations so that I can contract my vectors in a more natural way?

I suspect that the new builtin tensor support is supposed to be used differently than this (i.e. this doesn't seem like anything new, other than calling the array a tensor).

Also, is there a way to have this Array "tensors" display in an indexed fashion?  How would you specify if the tensor variable is upper or lower indexed?

EDIT: It was pointed out in the comments that Assumptions can be used to declare a symbolic tensor, but it's not obvious to me how to make this do something useful.  For example, if declare

```
$Assumptions = c \[Element] Matrices[{2, 1}, Reals] ; 
$Assumptions = d \[Element] Matrices[{2, 1}, Reals] ;
$Assumptions = e \[Element] Matrices[{1, 2}, Reals] ;
$Assumptions = f \[Element] Matrices[{1, 2}, Reals] ;
```

I'd assume one of these pairs of declarations (I'm not sure which), to be a rank 1 tensor with two elements, but if I try to contract this as I did above with the array declaration

```
c . n . d
e . n . f
```

I get:

```
c.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}.d
e.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}.f
```

respectively.  I can also manually "declare" a subscript notation "tensor"

```
w = {Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2]} 
q = {Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2]}
```

While I'm not sure how to declare this with Array, or some other less manual way, this at least solves the notation issue.  I can then contract that with `w. n . q` yielding

$u_1 v_1-u_2 v_2$

Again, none of this looks like it is anything what I'd expect from the advertised new "native" version 9 support for tensors (something like what the Ricci package appears to support).

Comment: The docs have information on symbolic tensors, which are set up using "Assumptions->". But I found no example for metrics, or for indexed notation.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15307/245) will be useful.