# simplification rule with symmetry

Tags: replacement

What rule can you think of to replace the first line by the second?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have a bunch of expression like these, which I would like to simplify. All  dependent cross terms must be written in the same order, using $\epsilon^{i j} A_i \times B_j = \epsilon^{i j} B_i \times A_j $.

The other expressions look like this, but there are a few differences:

- The names of the fields in the crossproduct differ; e.g. $e_{2 i}$ and $\omega_{2 i}$ instead of $e_{1 i}$ and $e_{2 i}$
- The sum can contain more terms. In particular it can contain more cross products
- Terms that are dependent may not appear right after each other in the sum

Which rule would cover all such expressions?

This is the input for the first line.

```
ϵ^ij*((σ*Cross[Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], i], Subscript[Subscript[ω, 1], j]]*Subscript[M, 1])/4 + (σ*Cross[Subscript[Subscript[ω, 1], i], Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], j]]*Subscript[M, 1])/4)
```

Comment: The only correct answer is to not use replacement rules and instead do it mathematically. Also, ditch the subscripts. Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463/5

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297/245) is of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ϵ^ij*((σ*Cross[Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], i], Subscript[Subscript[ω, 1], j]]*Subscript[M, 1])/4 +
     (σ*Cross[Subscript[Subscript[ω, 1], i], Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], j]]*Subscript[M, 1])/4 +
     (σ*Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], j]*Subscript[M, 1]*Subscript[P, 1])/2) /. 
 {Cross[Subscript[A_, i_], Subscript[B_, j_]] /; OrderedQ[{B, A}] :> 
   Cross[Subscript[B, i], Subscript[A, j]]}

(* ϵ^ij (1/ 2 σ Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], i]\[Cross]Subscript[Subscript[ω, 1], j] Subscript[M, 1] + 
   1/2 σ Subscript[M, 1] Subscript[P, 1] Subscript[Subscript[e, 1], j]) *)
```

It gives the right answer to your first question. You can check the second.  Ditching the subscripts is good advice, too.  You can use `Format` if you want subscripts in the output.